# Wiki inside of Salesforce?

Tags: businessprocess

I am new to SF and would like to build something like a wiki of information about processes and best practices for my organization. Since they will be using SF a lot going forward, I thought it might be nice to have this somewhere inside of the webapp in a Wiki of some sort.

Does SF support anything of this nature? Doesn't necessarily have to be a Wiki per se, but maybe something else that would accomplish the goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Check topic called Salesforce Knowledge -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_whatis.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.nl%2F&type=0

Comment: Yes knowledge is the best native feature for this.